# ¿Cómo encontrar el mínimo de una matriz?

Tags: c++, matrices

Estoy aprendiendo algunas cosas sobre matrices en dev c++, y esta vez me han pedido que encuentre y muestre en un arreglo (por eso he puesto D[4]) el valor mínimo de cada una de las 4 columnas de la última matriz que saqué.
En seguida les muestro lo que tengo en mi código:

```
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int s=0,A[4][4],B[4][4],C[4][4],D[4],i,j,inf,sup,m,P;

srand(time(NULL));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

printf("Dame el límite inferior de la matriz y el límite superior de la matriz: \n");
scanf("%d %d",&inf,&sup);
printf("\nEl múltiplo de la matriz es 3, por lo que queda de la siguiete forma:\n");

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        do
        {
            A[i][j]=rand()%(sup-inf)+inf;
        }while(A[i][j]%3!=0);
        printf("%d\t",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n\n");
printf("La transpuesta es:\n");


for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",A[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n¿Qué número quieres multiplicarle a la matriz transpuesta?: ");
scanf("%d",&m);

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        A[j][i]*m;
        B[j][i]=(A[j][i]*m);
        printf("%d\t",B[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\nAhora, la suma de la matriz multiplicada más la matriz original es:\n");


for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        C[i][j]=(A[i][j]+B[j][i]);
        printf("%d\t",C[i][j]);
        C[i][j]=P;
    }printf("\n");
}
```

Esta última es la matriz sobre la que tengo que sacar los mínimos y los he intentado sacar con lo siguiente:

```
printf("\nPor último, de la matriz sumada, te mostraré los valores más pequeños de cada columna:\n");

for(i=0;i<4;)
{
    if(P<=C[i][j])
    {
        C[i][j]=P;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        P=P;
        j++;
    }
    D[i]=P;
}
}
```

pero sólo me muestra puros 0. Espero que me puedan orientar y ayudar para saber qué tengo que hacer para poder mostrar al usuario el mínimo de cada **columna**. Por ejemplo, en mi matriz de 4x4 me sale lo siguiente:

```
5 8 9 4
1 2 3 4
7 6 9 7
9 4 5 6
```

Ahora, los mínimos valores de cada columna serían los siguientes:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: El código es [tag:c++] sólo por el `using namespace`, el resto es completamente [tag:c].

Comment: Me surgen varias dudas,  la suma de las matrices te funciona bien?, de donde sale P, si lo único que te interesa es hallar el mínimo pq das la explicación de la suma de las matrices eso más que ayudar confunde, hay que ser claro y conciso, y por último aunque parezca una bobería estas seguro que es el mínimo de las columnas, no será el mínimo de las filas

Comment: @Japv, sí, la suma sí me funciona a la perfección. 
La P la declaré para poder igualarla a la matriz C, tal vez eso sea un proceso innecesario, pero reitero, soy nuevo en esto, y no tengo mucha idea.
Y sí, estoy seguro de que es la suma de las columnas, así me lo ha pedido mi maestra.

Comment: Y por fin es el mínimo de las filas o de las columnas, es muy importante que estés bien claro en esto

Comment: @Japv, como te lo he dicho, es el mínimo de las columnas, ya he editado mi texto, gracias.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 el mínimo es 1, es eso lo que pides

Comment: Ahhh, vale, tienes mucha razón, ya te he entendido, permíteme modificar mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int min;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   min = matriz[0, i];

   for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
   {
      if(matriz[j, i] < min)
      {
         min = matriz[j, i];
      }
   }

   //Imprime min con la función printf
}
```

Se hacen dos **ciclos for anidados** y se va recorriendo la matriz verticalmente, se toma como referencia que la **variable min** es el primer elemento de esa columna y en caso de encontrarse un elemento en esa columna menor que la **variable min**, pues entonces la **variable min** toma este nuevo valor, posteriormente se imprime este valor.

Comment: ¡EXACTAMENTE ESO NECESITABA! Muchísimas gracias :)